# Chrome: How can I avoid that my users get a Data Breach Change Your Password Notification

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, password-protection

Are there any special actions/implementations that can be made as a frontend developer to avoid that users receive the following **Data Breach Change Your Password Notification** in Chrome browser, like to ensure that the users choose a "strong password" when they register?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As frontend developer, the only way that I know is forcing special characters, uppercase and lowercase digits on your registration form.